# Получить объект из списка по свойству

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый день, имеется список объектов (Photo, Video, Gallery, PhotoMode, VideoMode). Как можно получить галерею по её имени?
Пока что идея такая:

```
   static public List<Object> list = new List<Object>();
   list.Where(x=>x is Gallery).ToList().Single(x=>x.Name)
```

То есть из общего списка объектов сначала получить список всех галерей, затем из всех выбрать одну.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 static public List<Object> list = new List<Object>();
list.OfType<Gallery>().SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Name == %GALLERY_NAME%)
```

%GALLERY_NAME% замените на имя нужной галереи

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, помог, ещё с одним вопросом помогите, пожалуйста)))
на вход поступает массив строк, которые являются именами режимов. Нужно получить список режимов, которые имеют заданные имена.

Comment: @MichaelParshyn: Это уже новый вопрос, задавайте его лучше отдельно.